# Integration tests - Setup data in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, integration-testing

I need to write integration tests for my layer that exposes methods of service. But I need my database to be in a certain state for the tests to pass

For example for testing the GetStoreByID method, I need to have store 1 in my database but not store 2 (for the ko test)

The database is developed and deployed by a another team using a sql project (dacpac)

I use Entity Framework 6.1.3 with an Edmx

What is the best way, in this case, to setup the data in database before tests ?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to your question, but having two teams integrate on a database is generally considered "not a good idea" as it often means that the two teams work in "lockstep", i.e. a deployment to the database will often require other teams to deploy at the same time. The solution is to introduce some sort of API boundary that lets you make database changes while retaining backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If your data access is separated by an interface (i.e. using something like IDBSet for each of the types), personally I'd avoid depending on the database completely where possible, and use either a [fakedbsets](https://gist.github.com/rally25rs/1492134) (if you need to test repository/DAL code) or just mocking with moq or [nsubstitute](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/unit-testing-nbuilder-fake-or-mock-dbset/) if you don't.

I know this doesn't specifically answer your question, but the best way to setup test data is do it in memory in my experience with as few external dependencies as possible. The database adds extra moving parts that you don't really want to have to depend on in unit/integration tests. This also adds complexities if you have a CI server etc... that you generally want to avoid.

Comment: Hello! I use already Rhino.Mocks for my unit tests. I thought it was not advisable to "simulate" dependencies during integration tests. Is it possible to use the memory with EF 6? How do I configure the data beforehand? Thank!

Comment: hi @Azerty123 I actually quite like the testdouble approach where you mock out the whole context personally. So basically your EF db sets are lists. It does rely on you having a dbcontext that implements an interface, and then using something like https://gist.github.com/rally25rs/1492134 to act as the fake db set.

Answer (score 0):

This link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314431(v=vs.113).aspx gives the Microsoft MSDN article on how to write tests using EF6 by faking out the database.

In summary the article covers the subject 'When writing tests for your application it is often desirable to avoid hitting the database. Entity Framework allows you to achieve this by creating a context – with behavior defined by your tests – that makes use of in-memory data.'